# How to find HTML elements with values contained in a given array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors

### Problem

Given this piece of code:

```html
<ul>
  <li><input type="hidden" value="1"/>Choice 1</li>
  <li><input type="hidden" value="2"/>Choice 2</li>
  <li><input type="hidden" value="3"/>Choice 3</li>
  <li><input type="hidden" value="4"/>Choice 4</li>
  <li><input type="hidden" value="5"/>Choice 5</li>
</ul>
```

How can I properly select list elements that has an input with a value contained in the array `[1, 3, 4]`?

---

### Research track

I tried some solutions in this code snippet, but nothing seems to work nicely.

```js
alert($("li").has("input[value='3']").text());  // Not a solution
alert($("li").has("input[value='[1,3,4]']").text());  // Not working
alert($("li").has("input[value=[1,3,4]]").text());  // Not working 
alert($("li").has("input[value=['1','3','4']]").text());  // Nope
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li><input type="hidden" value="1"/>Choice 1</li>
  <li><input type="hidden" value="2"/>Choice 2</li>
  <li><input type="hidden" value="3"/>Choice 3</li>
  <li><input type="hidden" value="4"/>Choice 4</li>
  <li><input type="hidden" value="5"/>Choice 5</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `filter()` to find the `li` from the relevant child `input` elements.

```js
var valueArr = [1, 3, 4];
var $li = $('li').filter(function() {
  return valueArr.indexOf(parseInt($(this).find('input').val(), 10)) != -1;
});
$li.css('color', '#C00'); // just to make the effect obvious
console.log($li.text());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>
    <input type="hidden" value="1" />Choice 1</li>
  <li>
    <input type="hidden" value="2" />Choice 2</li>
  <li>
    <input type="hidden" value="3" />Choice 3</li>
  <li>
    <input type="hidden" value="4" />Choice 4</li>
  <li>
    <input type="hidden" value="5" />Choice 5</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Yeah but I need to select the list elements, not the inputs. So I'd need to add `var $li = $inputs.parent("li");` right?

Comment: No problem, glad to help

Answer (score 2):

You can use **[`filter()`](https://api.jquery.com/filter/)** here

```js
alert($("li").filter(function() {
  return [1, 3, 4].indexOf(parseInt($('input', this).val(), 10)) > -1;
}).text());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>
    <input type="hidden" value="1" />Choice 1</li>
  <li>
    <input type="hidden" value="2" />Choice 2</li>
  <li>
    <input type="hidden" value="3" />Choice 3</li>
  <li>
    <input type="hidden" value="4" />Choice 4</li>
  <li>
    <input type="hidden" value="5" />Choice 5</li>
</ul>
```

---

Or use **[multiple attribute selector](https://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/)**

```js
alert($("li").has('[value=1],[value=3],[value=4]').text()); // Not working
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>
    <input type="hidden" value="1" />Choice 1</li>
  <li>
    <input type="hidden" value="2" />Choice 2</li>
  <li>
    <input type="hidden" value="3" />Choice 3</li>
  <li>
    <input type="hidden" value="4" />Choice 4</li>
  <li>
    <input type="hidden" value="5" />Choice 5</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
var arr = ['1', '3', '4'];

$('ul li').filter(function() {

  return $.inArray($(this).find('input').val(), arr) != -1; //  if found return and add class red

}).addClass('red')
```

```css
.red {
  background-color: red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>
    <input type="hidden" value="1" />Choice 1</li>
  <li>
    <input type="hidden" value="2" />Choice 2</li>
  <li>
    <input type="hidden" value="3" />Choice 3</li>
  <li>
    <input type="hidden" value="4" />Choice 4</li>
  <li>
    <input type="hidden" value="5" />Choice 5</li>
</ul>
```

Do like this

Answer (score 0):

We have to get multiple attribute selector format as

```
$("li").has("input[value='1'],input[value='3'],input[value='4']");
```

Using `reduce` to get it from `array`

```js
var arr = [1,3,4];

document.write($("li").has(arr.reduce(function(prev,next){
  return prev + ",input[value='"+next+"']";
},"").slice(1)).text());
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script><ul>
  <li><input type="hidden" value="1"/>Choice 1</li>
  <li><input type="hidden" value="2"/>Choice 2</li>
  <li><input type="hidden" value="3"/>Choice 3</li>
  <li><input type="hidden" value="4"/>Choice 4</li>
  <li><input type="hidden" value="5"/>Choice 5</li>
</ul>
```